# Is this proof that 10/11• 110/111•1110/1111•...= 9/10 valid?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$$\begin{align}9/10 &= 10/11\cdot  99/100 \\&= 10/11\cdot110/111\cdot999/1000\\&= 10/11\cdot 110/111\cdot 1110/1111\cdot 9999/10000\\&=\dots\end{align}$$

Here we see that following this pattern, one of the factors get closer and closer to 1:

$$\begin{align}99/100 &= 0.99\\ 
999/1000 &= 0.999\\
9999/10000 &= 0.9999\end{align}$$
... Ad infinitum = 0.999 ... = 1

And at infinity (so to speak)  multiplying by 1 doesn't change the number, therefore the infinite product is equal to 9/10.

Is this sort of reasoning enough to establish that, or is it necessary to also consider convergence to a limit?

Comment: Learn how to properly phrase a [Proof By Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).  That is how you will formalize this "*ad infinitum*" argument.

Comment: If you wanted to rigorously prove it, you definitely need to do more

Comment: As for "*If we multiply by things repeatedly where those things approach $1$, what happens*" that depends.  It can be worse than you hope, in exactly the same way that infinite sums whose terms approach zero might yet misbehave.  Note the relation between infinite products $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and infinite sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \log(a_k)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, I'm only a beginner when it comes to math so I guess I'll have to study proof by induction more in depth. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Hint 1:
The product you have in question can be represented as:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{i=2}^n \frac {10^n-10}{10^n-1}$$
All you have to do is evaluate this limit.

Hint 2: Use telescopic product technique to find a closed form for this product, then tend $n$ towards $\infty$.